# Does Silverlight support WebHttpBinding?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, rest, silverlight-3.0

Does Silverlight 3.0 support WebHttpBinding for WCF RESTful services?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: Somebody has downvoted my answer. This documentation clarifies it. WebHttpBinding is not supported "out of the box" in SL3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470110(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd540823(VS.95).aspx
Believe it is a security restriction.

Comment: The whole point of WebHttpBinding is to allow a server to expose http endpoints.  Silverlight can consume http services.  There is no support for doing "Add Service Reference" from a Silverlight client to a WCF service using WebHttpBinding because that would be pointless.  I downvoted your answer because the fact that this capability does not exist has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Fair point, but maybe a comment to that effect would have done. :)